# Get-WinEvent convert to html got only one line in output table

Tags: html, events, powershell

I'm trying to output all the specific events to html and always get only the last line in the table.

Here is the following HTML code-

```html
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='System'; id=1074}  |
ForEach-Object {

    $rv = New-Object PSObject | Select-Object Date, User, Action, Process, Reason, ReasonCode, Comment
    $rv.Date = $_.TimeCreated
    $rv.User = $_.Properties[6].Value
    $rv.Process = $_.Properties[0].Value
    $rv.Action = $_.Properties[4].Value
    $rv.Reason = $_.Properties[2].Value
    $rv.ReasonCode = $_.Properties[3].Value
    $rv.Comment = $_.Properties[5].Value
    $rv
}

#this style reason for restart.
$header = "<H3>Print Server Log Report "+(get-date -f D)+"</H3>"  
$title = "Example HTML Output" 
$body = '<style>  
BODY{font-family:Verdana; background-color:white;}  
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style:solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}  
TH{font-size:1em; border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#C2B8AF}  
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style:  solid;border-color: black;background-color:#F6F8FC}  
</style>'

$rv | Select-Object Date,User, Action, Reason, Comment | Convertto-html -head $header -body $body > c:\scripts\test.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a foreach loop, you're setting an $rv object in the loop, but it doesn't appear that you're doing anything else with the $rv object *inside the loop.*

If you want all of the things you're foreaching over, to be printed, output, whatever, instead of just the last one, you have to do that print, output, whatever, *inside the loop,* not outside of it.  Do it after the loop, and you'll only get the last one.

Comment: How to get it outside of the loop?

Comment: You mean "how to get it *inside* of the loop," don't you?  If your question is "how do I iterate over all of my values outside of the loop," the answer is "you can't."